# Hacer suma de 2 tablas diferentes my sql

Tags: mysql, join, union

Hola Estoy tratando de hacer una suma de 1 columna de una tabla y otra suma de otra tabla.
y que me de el resultado en columnas diferentes

pero solo logre que me diera el resultado en 1 solo columna con 2 filas.

SELECT SUM(hcdl) FROM `produccion` WHERE fecha = "2022-07-20" AND turno = "TURNO1" UNION SELECT SUM(cantidad_personas) as test FROM `idl` WHERE fecha = "2022-07-20" AND turno = "TURNO1"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

otra opcion fue la siguiente pero no suma correctamente los valores de la tabla
SELECT SUM(produccion.hcdl) AS hcdl ,SUM(idl.cantidad_personas) AS cantidad_personas FROM `produccion`,`idl`  WHERE produccion.fecha = "2022-07-20" AND produccion.turno = "TURNO1" AND  idl.fecha = "2022-07-20" AND idl.turno = "TURNO1"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Porque queres eso? dicho esto, para poner una columna al lado de otra, de alguna forma deberias usar un join.. y ademas, usar un group by... pero, me parece que nada de eso necesitas, si nos decis porque queres meter dos sumas que nada que ver una al lado de la otra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder mostrar las columnas separadas necesitas utilizar la tabla DUAL la cual fue creada por Charles Weiss de Oracle Corporation para proporcionar una tabla para unir vistas y consultas internas.

Para ello debes hacer un SELECT de SELECT el cual según tus datos debería quedar asi:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT SUM(hcdl) FROM eventos WHERE fecha = "2022-07-20" AND turno = "TURNO1") as hcdl,
    (SELECT SUM(cantidad_personas) FROM idl WHERE fecha = "2022-07-20" AND turno = "TURNO1") AS test
from dual
```

IMPORTANTE: La tabla DUAL fue creada por Oracle, pero hoy en día está presente en la mayoría de las Bases de Datos, incluyendo MySQL.

Comment: Funciono muy bien :) , gracias

Comment: @DarioMaldonado Recuerda que esto solo funciona si la respuesta contiene una única fila si no te genera el error "#1242 - Subconsulta retorna más que 1 línea"